# How to call function if the value changes in any text input with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call function if another function changes the value of any text field with class netvalue.

```
<input name="1" type="text" class="netvalue" readonly>
<input name="2" type="text" class="netvalue" readonly>
<input name="3" type="text" class="netvalue" readonly>

<script>
$(".netvalue").oninput(function(){
       confirm('changed');   
});     
<script>
```

Comment: $(".netvalue").trigger('oninput');

Comment: Your question is not clear. `input` event should catch changes via javascript as well. Add an example of **not working** code.

Comment: @Talib not its not working, even try onchange :(

Comment: share working example of your issue.

Comment: <script>
$(".netvalue").onchange(function(){
       confirm('changed');   
});     
<script>

Comment: Why do you want to fire a change event on readonly field?

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ucr46Lyx/ As **Talib Allauddin** has suggested, wherever you change the value via Js/jQuery just add `.trigger('change')` to the end of it as shown in my example. You can use `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')` if you wish to find the id or other attribute to that specific element. `$(this).attr('ElementAttribute')`

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an input-change.

```js
$(".netvalue").change(function(){
  console.log('changed')
});
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("input[name='1']").val("some text");
  $(".netvalue").trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Insert text</button>
<input name="1" type="text" class="netvalue" >
<input name="2" type="text" class="netvalue" >
<input name="3" type="text" class="netvalue" >
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to trigger the change function inside the function that is changing the value of the input.

see below

```js
var input = $(".netvalue"),
    but = $("button")
$(but).on("click",function() {
   $(input).val("1").trigger("change")
})

$(input).on("change",function() {
   alert("changed")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="1" type="text" class="netvalue" readonly>
<input name="2" type="text" class="netvalue" readonly>
<input name="3" type="text" class="netvalue" readonly>
<button>
clickME
</button>
```